# Where are these places and why are they all within 100 miles of each other?

Tags: geography

These places are easy enough to figure out:

- Sheffield Wednesday's home
- Liffey's mouth
- Queensland's capital
- Turin's region
- New York's capital
- The Queen's favourite weekend home

But why are they all within 100 miles of each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because

> They are all in Northern California (the Bay Area specifically)

Sheffield Wednesday's home

> Hillsborough

Liffey's mouth

> Dublin

Queensland's capital

> Brisbane

Turin's region

> Piedmont

New York's capital

> Albany

The Queen's favourite weekend home

> Windsor

Comment: This really is a good question. Kinda not fair since I grew up there. :)